# How to close picker in React Native?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm using Native Base picker.
I want to close it manually but can't find API for this.
Component not contain any methods or props like `visible`.

How I can to close/hide picker?

Comment: Looks like it only comes with the default closing action, you should take a look at it code and see what method it calls to close the picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **my** case it's enough to use `renderHeader` function with `backAction` parameter

```
<Picker
    renderHeader={backAction => (
        <Button onPress={() => {
            backAction();
            someFunction();
        }}
    )}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

a): you could simply render it based on this.state.isPickerVisible, or b): wrap it in a Modal which has a visible prop

for closing the Picker, if you opt to wrap it in a Modal, then make the modal take up the whole screen and use Touchable without feedback to handle taps outside of the Picker: `<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.cancelPressed()}>` where cancel pressed toggles isPickerVisible

```
{this.state.isPickerVisible && 
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.tempGender}
  onValueChange={tempGender => this.setState({tempGender})}
>
  <Picker.Item label="Female" value="female" />
  <Picker.Item label="Male" value="male" />
  <Picker.Item label="Other" value="other" />
</Picker>}
```

if you opt to wrap it in a Modal, then you can get some animation options

```
import {Modal, Picker ... etc...} from 'react-native'

    <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}
      visible={this.state.isPickerVisible}
    >
 <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.cancelPressed()}>
  <View>
    <Picker
      selectedValue={this.state.tempGender}
      onValueChange={tempGender => this.setState({tempGender})}
    >
      <Picker.Item label="Female" value="female" />
      <Picker.Item label="Male" value="male" />
      <Picker.Item label="Other" value="other" />
    </Picker>
  </View>
 </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</Modal>
```

Comment: I tried with `this.state.isPickerVisible` and I don't like visual behaviour

Comment: If you want animation, try wrapping it in a modal so it slides in and out, or fades in and out.